# Is it considered rape if a victim doesn't understand what is happening?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, sexual-assault, rape, kentucky

If a person engages in sexual intercourse with another who lacks sexual education is it a crime?  If so what is the crime?

More specifically, suppose the innocent party is a minor (say around 12 years old) who does not know about sex.  Suppose also that the perpetrator is a minor but does have sexual education.

I'm particularly interested in law applicable to Kentucky.

Answer (score 10):

If she was under 16, it's rape. A child under that age cannot consent to intercourse.

If she's older, it may still be sex abuse, which includes subjecting a person to sexual contact without express or implied consent. It may also still be rape, but I'm less clear on how Kentucky courts define implied consent.

Comment: But the guy was also under 16...  I thought if the other party is also a minor, then it's okay?

Comment: It depends on the age of each of them. I can't say without knowing both ages.

Comment: I believe Kentucky has no exceptions to the rule, regardless of age. Thus the statutory rape statute should still apply to a 15 year old.

Comment: As an aside: if "she didn't understand" then it would be rape in England and Wales - regardless of age.  It would definitely be under-age sex (not rape), and if she was 12 rather than 13, it would be "rape of a child under 13" (https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/5).

Answer (score 6):

**YES!**   -  "I don't understand" isn't consent and, in any case, she is below the age of consent in Kentucky by 3 years. It is really hard to understand the need for this question in 2020.

Comment: Note the question was posed 2 years ago, but yes, it should be obvious.

Comment: It *should* be obvious, but sometimes the law doesn’t give the obvious result. This answer and, to a lesser extent, the comment above, come off as a little condescending.

Comment: @BrianDrake - I toned down my initial reaction before posting. I am horrified that anyone capable of posting to this site does not know that sex without consent is rape.